# multithread summation with java

Tags: java, multithreading

I intend to get summation from 1 to 10000000 using multithread,
below code doesn't work correctly in this line - `sum = sum + Sum(finalI, finalI * step);`, the sum is always 0 in current thread. I have already added `volatile`, I'm new to java I don't know how to solve this.

```
package test;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class testParallelFor {
    volatile static long sum = 0;
    final static int step = 100;
    final static int start = 1;
    final static int end = 10000000;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int num = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(num);
        try {
            for (int i = start; i < end; i = i * step) {
                int finalI = i;
                exec.submit(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        sum = sum + Sum(finalI, finalI * step);
                    }
                });
            }

        } finally {
            exec.shutdown();
            exec.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
            sum = sum + end;
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
    }

    static long Sum(int i, int j) {
        System.out.println("Sum from " + i + " to " + j + " start.");
        long temp = 0;
        for (int k = i; k < j; k++) {
            temp = temp + k;
        }
        System.out.println("Sum from " + i + " to " + j + " end. sum=" + temp);
        return temp;
    }
}
```

output:

```
Sum from 1 to 100 start.
Sum from 1000000 to 100000000 start.
Sum from 100 to 10000 start.
Sum from 10000 to 1000000 start.
Sum from 1 to 100 end. sum=4950
Sum from 100 to 10000 end. sum=49990050
Sum from 10000 to 1000000 end. sum=499949505000
Sum from 1000000 to 100000000 end. sum=4999499950500000
4999499960500000
```

Comment: If you're using an executor, submit a `Callable<Long>` instead.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- I doubt that this really matters here. This code is so overly "weird" ...

Comment: @AndyTurner I think you mean *long* ???

Comment: A `volatile` `long` can't be incremented atomically. Another thread can read/write in between the current thread's read and write.

Comment: @AndyTurner it's true that `long` and `double` don't guarantee atomic read and write, but make them `volatile` and they do. See this section of JLS: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7

Comment: @diginoise `a = a + b;` (and `a += b;`) involves reading `a`, reading `b`, adding them, and writing the result back to `a`. Each of those actions is individually atomic, but other actions can interleave them. Otherwise, you wouldn't need `AtomicInteger` etc.

Comment: @AndyTurner good point! It's 2 reads and 1 write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the sum is always 0 in current thread

That's possible (although not guaranteed) because of the evaluation order of the expression:

```
sum+ Sum(finalI, finalI * step)
```

`sum` is read *before* invoking `Sum`; and `Sum` is slow when it's called for a large input range.

All the threads are started at roughly the same time, and the very first thing they will do is to read `sum`. Unless it has already been updated by another thread, the thread will read the initial value, evaluate `Sum`, and then add the result back to the `sum` variable without checking to see if `sum` was updated in the interim.

You could do the slow evaluation of `Sum` prior to reading `sum`:

```
sum = Sum(finalI, finalI * step) + sum;
```

but you still have the issue that the read of `sum` and the write of the updated `sum` are performed atomically: another thread can update `sum` in between, and then this thread would stomp that thread's update.

You would need to use some sort of synchronization to ensure that updates happen atomically; or use something like `AtomicLong` or `LongAdder`, which can be updated atomically.

Or use the Executor better, so you don't need to worry about synchronization of the updates to sum:

```
List<Future<Long>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = start; i < end;i = i * step) {
  int finalI = i;
  futures.add(exec.submit(() -> Sum(finalI, finalI * step)));
}

long sum = 0;  // No need to be volatile if you update in a single thread.
for (Future<Long> future : futures) {
  sum += future.get();
}
```

Or use parallel streams, as in [Abrikot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59660572/3788176).

Comment: Your solution is the one I was looking for while using an Executor. That's probably the best one we could find. @amingo, go for it!

Comment: The reason is not `sum` is read before invoking `Sum`, "Program order rule" doesn't mean that invoking `Sum` must be subsequent to `sum`. The reason is before any read of `sum`, no write to `sum` has happened.

Comment: @Andy Turner Exactly what i need.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest solution would probably to use parallel streams:

```
long start = 1;
long end = 10000000;
long result = LongStream.rangeClosed(start, end)  // Creates a stream going from 1 to 10000000
        .parallel()  // Parallelize this stream
        .sum();      // Sums every value of this stream
System.out.println(result);
```

That's much more clear than your version :)

Comment: Very great solution!  What i'm really doing was to learn java multitthread via coding something. I undertand how to solve this kind of quesiton now by your solution, but i still need to know how to fix my code. thank you very mucn.

Comment: @AndyTurner I agree with the fact it's not telling why the OP's approach does not work. I was thinking about "how to solve the issue", not "why this code is not working?". I have tried to point out that a clearer solution for summing in multithreading exists. Regarding your solution, the result is correct but it's not the sum that has been asked for.

Answer (score 0):

> the sum is always 0 in current thread

No, this is **not** true. You can replace `ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(num);` with `ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);`, you will see `sum` is 0 **only** in the first task. This is because there is only one thread, the tasks are executed sequentially, the next task will guarantee to see the change of `sum`.

```
// replace `ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(num);` with `ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);`
// add `System.out.printf("i: %d, sum: %d\n", finalI, sum);` in `run`
i: 1, sum: 0
i: 100, sum: 4950
i: 10000, sum: 49995000
i: 1000000, sum: 499999500000
```

When the number of threads >= the number of tasks, `sum` is **"always"** 0. This is because tasks can be executed concurrently, they see the initial 0 before other threads update `sum`.

But when the 1 < the number of threads < the number of tasks, you can't predict which tasks will see 0, which tasks will see the change. The only guarantee is that when the task is getting executed and start to read `sum`, it will see the latest `sum`.

Comment: "No, this is not true." But it *is* true for OP's code. The word "always" might not be correct (in the sense that it is not guaranteed), but OP is saying "I observe it to be 0", which *is* possible when using multiple threads. Changing it to use a single thread changes the behavior.

Comment: Yes, that's why I use "always", not always.